# Rails_admin mass assignment error with Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rails-admin, strong-parameters, mass-assignment

I just updated to Rails 4 and rails_admin is now giving me this when I try to edit anything and then hit save:

```
Can't mass-assign protected attributes for Opportunity: created_by_id, contact_information, sent_expiring_email
```

From what I read [here](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Mass-assignments-protection) it looks like rails_admin is not supposed to allow non-attr-accessible things to be editable but that seems to be the case.

I understand that moving to strong parameters would fix this. Is that the case? Is there a different way to fix it? Or if not can someone provide a simple explanation of how to move to strong parameters. I've tried the usual googling and reading up on it but I don't really understand what's going on and what I would need to change in my code to make the move.

Answer (score 0):

Strong parameters is part of Rails since rails 4. To disable strong parameters, you can add the following line in your application.rb.

`config.action_controller.permit_all_parameters = true`

**It is not recommended to disable strong_parameters**

You can also take a look at https://github.com/rails/protected_attributes